# Need help in extracting tables with rows of font bold to a pandas data-frame using python

Tags: python-3.x, tabula, python-camelot

I have a few pdfs where we have different tables and in tables, we have few rows which are in bold font. Is there a way to extract the rows in bold font as a bold row with remaining rows as a normal font to the pandas' data frame using tabula or Camelot?

Comment: Some working code sample!

Comment: I am just using Tabula or Camelot to extract

Comment: Please explain better your question. Did you try? Did you encounter problems?

Comment: See in a pdf there are 10 rows and in the 8th row, the first column is in bold font. So how do you keep font bond while extracted as a pandas data frame using tabula or camelot